# C# INSERT command doesn't work unless database table is empty

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-insert, sqlcommand

I am having an issue with a school assignment.
For some reason, my sql INSERT command doesn't wotk unless the database table is empty.
If it is empty, it works just fine, but if I use if while there are already entries there, it moves to my "catch" block.

My initial connection and reading from the database to load the items was successful.
The following code also succeeds IF I remove the first "for" block (i.e. if I start my connection by deleting all the data from the table and insert the new data after that. Please read the long comment as to why I did two identical "for" blocks to begin with).

If I delete the firs "for" block and also remove the "DELETE" command, it still doesn't work (i.e. the problem isn't the two identical "for" blocks, but something else which prevents the INSERT command from working unless the table is empty).

Using MessageBox.Show I have tested how far the "try" block goes before going to the "catch" block. I have inserted //--// into that place in the following code. As you can see, the last successful line is before the INSERT command.

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Favorite fav;
            SqlCommand delfav = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM tblFavorites", conn);
            SqlCommand addfav = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblFavorites (Title, url) VALUES (@title, @url)", conn);
            addfav.Parameters.Add("@title", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
            addfav.Parameters.Add("@url", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 300);
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                for (int i = 0; i < favorites.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    fav = (Favorite)favorites.Items[i];
                    addfav.Parameters["@title"].Value = fav.getsettitle;
                    addfav.Parameters["@url"].Value = fav.getseturl;
                    //--//
                    addfav.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                /*
                At first I didn't have the above section. The result was that each time the browser closed,
                it first deleted the database table and then if there was a problem uploading the new data,
                the old list was already gone.
                To correct for this, I first attempted to add the favorites to the list (despite the fact
                that for a short time it will have double the amount of information). If this process is
                unsuccessful, it will skip to the catch block and the original data will be saved.
                Only if the INSERT command is successful, I delete the data, then repeat the INSERT command,
                already knowing that it is successful.
                */
                delfav.ExecuteNonQuery();
                for (int i = 0; i < favorites.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    fav = (Favorite)favorites.Items[i];
                    addfav.Parameters["@title"].Value = fav.getsettitle;
                    addfav.Parameters["@url"].Value = fav.getseturl;
                    addfav.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("There was a problem loading your favorites to the database. Do you still wish to quit? \n (All changes to the favorites list will be lost)", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                if (dialogResult != DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

Thanx a lot for your help guys!

Comment: Can you show us the design of `tblFavorites`?

Comment: By saying `The insert command does not work`, does it throw any error? If yes, can you please provide it?

Comment: Doc, I'm not sure how to show you the design. It's just two columns called "Title" and "url", both nVarChar, title with 100 and url with 300 limits (you can see the parameters I used in the code, they are an exact match).

choz - it doesn't give an error message, it just skips to the "catch" block, indicating that it failed to insert somehow if I understand correctly. It only shows the YesNo message box I inserted manually (which is what I want it to do).

Comment: I suspect the error is duplicate primary key  @choz

Comment: Ah, that would make a lot of sense, because I'm not checking for that at all, and I do indeed reload things which are already in the database, which would create duplicates.
I'll try and remove the primary key in the database for testing and post the results in a moment.

Comment: @dotctor Kay, then I suspect the culprit is a `unique constraint` on either `Title` or `Url` column.

Comment: Ok guys, thank you very much!
The problem was indeed the primary key issue.

How do I flag this as solved without any answers?

Comment: @NimrodYanai You can ask the person who wrote the helpful comment to write it as an answer, then when they have done so come back and accept their answer.